# Selenium - element is not visible

Tags: selenium

I am trying to enter text into a text box and below is the error I get:

An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

However, this element is interactable and you can enter text into it.
The displayed field for the element is false.
Is there a way to override this an force selenium to enter the text?
Perhaps using javascript? If you have any ideas please let me know.

Many Thanks,
Rahul Dixit

Comment: First you have to enable that text box via selenium then try to enter text.

Comment: Can you show us on public url where we can mimick this scenario? And use of java script is always discouraged for you information.

Comment: You are contradicting yourself. First you say the element is interactable and text can be entered, and then you say the 'displayed' attribute of the element is 'false'(for which I am guessing the value is 'none'). How is it possible ? Also, in case the element is visible after certain amount of time, then try using [Explicit waits](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits)

Comment: Are you sure it's picking up the right element? Sometimes pages are styled in a way that means a dropdown may have a `select` element underneath but that is actually hidden and not visible and it's being displayed using various `div`'s. That kind of issue sounds similar here.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to do is execute javascript to enable textbox later you can run your selenium code

for example :

```
  String textbox = "document.getElementsByName('lname')[0].removeAttribute('disabled');";

  javascript.executeScript(textbox);

  Thread.sleep(3000);
```